# how can i use microsoft edge read aloud function in malayalam language on website page

Tags: html, windows, browser, microsoft-edge

How can I use Microsoft edge read-aloud function in the Malayalam language on a website page?

I can't read my (Malayalam) language text on my .html or any website page.

Comment: Is this a website you're creating or just viewing? If it's just viewing then your question is off-topic since it has nothing to do with programming.

Answer (score 1):

At present, the [Learning Tools](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/use-learning-tools-in-the-edge-browser-78a7a17d-52e1-47ee-b0ac-eff8539015e1) (Read aloud function) doesn't support the Malayalam language, you could check it from [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/languages-and-products-supported-by-immersive-reader-47f298d6-d92c-4c35-8586-5eb81e32a76e).

You could try to give a feedback on the [Microsoft Education Immersive Reader UserVoice forum](https://edu.uservoice.com/forums/919666-immersive-reader), to add this language support.